# »aufweichen« vs. »aufweichen lassen«

Tags: difference, modal-verb

Gibt es einen prinzipiellen Unterschied zwischen:

1. *aufweichen* und *aufweichen lassen;*
2. *auftauen* und *auftauen lassen.*

(Es geht mir dabei um den Einfluss von *lassen* und nicht um den Unterschied zwischen *auftauen* und *aufweichen.*)

Beispiele für den Gebrauch:

- > Man muss das Obst erst auftauen (lassen).
- > Man muss Reis erst im Wasser aufweichen (lassen).
- > Man muss ... erst im Wasser aufweichen (lassen).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Der Zusatz *lassen* deutet darauf hin, dass man nicht explizit eingreift, sondern dem Vorgang seinen Lauf lässt bzw. sich frei fortführen lässt:

> Obst erst auftauen lassen

heißt man stellt es hin und wartet, dass es – auf sagen wir natürliche Weise (z.B. durch die Raumtemperatur) – auftaut.

> Obst erst auftauen,

bedeutet hingegen: Man kann, sollte, muss aber nicht eingreifen, es ist einem eher freigestellt, es zu tun. Zum Beispiel in dem man das Obst in warmes Wasser tut oder es warm abspült oder es einfach in einen Teller tut und wartet, bis es auftaut!

Hierbei wird – meines Erachtens, evtl. ist das falsch – die Notwendigkeit des Eingreifens bei diesem Ausdruck – relativ – stärker betont!

---

Ebenso verhält es sich mit *aufweichen* und *aufweichen lassen*.

Answer (score 1):

Der Unterschied zwischen "auftauen" und "auftauen lassen" ist im allgemeinen Sprachgebrauch gering und man kann problemlos beide Varianten verwenden.

Ganz genau genommen bezieht sich "auftauen" auf die Aktion, die eine Person durchführt, d.h. "*jemand* lässt Obst auftauen". "Obst auftauen" hat mehr das Objekt "Obst" im Fokus.

Aber wie gesagt, ganz minimale Unterschiede, die im normalem Sprachgebrauch gar nicht unterschieden oder beachtet werden.